# Mysql display Chinese character as messy code while data fetched by Pymysql is normal

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I use pymysql to insert data(Chinese). The code is working and the result is ok when I use fetchall and print the result. However, when I manually log in the mysql, I find that the data is messy code when I use "select * from TB". Character encoding should be ok because it works when I manually insert Chinese into a new table.

Any suggestions please?

I checked the codings are "utf-8" when I run "show create database taoya" and "show create table TB".

The variable is like:

```
    +--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name                        | Value                          |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client                 | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_connection             | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_database               | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem             | binary                         |
| character_set_results                | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_server                 | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system                 | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir                   | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1                              |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

The code is as followings:

```
mysql= pymysql.connect(host=xx,user=xx,password=xxx, db="taoya",charset="utf8mb4")

try:
    with mysql.cursor() as cur:
        # cur.execute("set names 'utf8'")
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TB")
        sql = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TB(
        Commody CHAR(70) NOT NULL,
        Store   CHAR(20),
        Address CHAR(20),
        Price CHAR(20),
        Paid CHAR(40))
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
        '''
        cur.execute(sql)

        insertsql="INSERT INTO TB (Commody,Store,Address, Price,Paid) VALUES (%s, %s,%s,%s,%s)"
        data= ("牛 啊","hi","你好","$33","3人")

        cur.execute(insertsql,data)

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TB;")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        print(result)
        mysql.commit()
finally:
    mysql.close()
```

The result is ok:

```
(('牛 啊', 'hi', '你好', '$33', '3人'),)
```

From the mysql side:

```
mysql> select * from TB;
+------------+-------+---------+-------+------+
| Commody    | Store | Address | Price | Paid |
+------------+-------+---------+-------+------+
| 鐗涢€鍟   | hi    | 浣犲ソ    | $33   | 3浜 |
+------------+-------+---------+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2

```
#coding:utf-8  #for .py file
import sys
import locale
import os
import codecs

reload(sys)
print sys.getdefaultencoding() + "  - sys.getdefaultencoding()"
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
print sys.getdefaultencoding() + "  - sys.getdefaultencoding()"
print sys.stdout.encoding + " - sys.stdout.encoding:"
```

Linux?

```
echo 中文汉字;
env|grep LANG
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8

Don't forget to check your Terminal tool's encoding setting.
```

MySQL config:

```
check:
show variables like 'character%'; 
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';

for client:
SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4';

/*
for server:
SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
SET collation_database = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
SET collation_server = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
*/
```